# How to load np.array using tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices and map

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, tensor

I'm doing a implementation of Pix2Pix but from a vector to do something like vec2pix, I have the vectors in file.npy format, and I'm trying to load that, with the images to tensors, y used

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tr_urls)
```

where tr_urls are the name of the arrays and

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(load_train_image)
```

where load_train_image is the fuction to load the images, but here is where i have problems,

How can I load np.array as tensor? and,

The name of np.array is like image_name_0.npy and the name of image is image_name.jpg, on train_dataset I have all the names in np.array format, but in the fuction map that is a tensor not a string, How can I change the name from *_0.npy to *.jpg?

I tried

```
inimg = tf.cast(tf.io.read_file(INPATH + '\\' + filename), tf.float32)
```

and

```
inimg = tf.numpy_function(np.load, [INPATH + '\\' + filename], [tf.float32])
```

The code that I use to load the images works correctly, but I can't edit the name of the array to load the image.

With the first the map fuction finished correctly but when I tried to loop over the tensor I got

```
UnimplementedError: Cast string to float is not supported
 [[{{node Cast}}]] [Op:MakeIterator]
```